# Unable to add space after video and before my button

Tags: html, css

When I add padding to my css, it works but is messes up the video frame. I just want some spacing between my video and free demo button.Currently, the button is basically touching the bottom of video.

[image: html]

[image: css]

[image: site]

Comment: did you try to put the link inside <p></p> tags or put <br> next take out the images and add your code directly in the question

Comment: Do not provide scrrenshot of the code and errors ,instead put real code.

Answer (score 2):

Add some top margin to the **button**. `margin-top: 15px;`

Comment: Awesome, Please mark my answer as the answer if that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to add a `margin-top` to your button. Adding more padding to the video container will most likely just make the video larger.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use margin top but it isnt responsive.
Best practice is to use a grid, bootstrap grid etc, or a simple html table.